# How to conditional disable input depend on another input value in "React-hook-form'?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I want to conditional disable input based on another input value. The common use case is we have a checkbox and we need to disable/enable another input in the same form. How could I achieve it with react-hook-form? I want to disable, not about validation when submit.

Currently, I am using `FormControlLabel` (material-ui) with react-hook-form for that. Any help will be appreciated.

Updated!
Here is a small demo code for my idea

```
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { FormControlLabel, Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

const { control } = useForm({/* some options */});

// Below is render function

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Controller
  name="checkbox"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value }}) => {
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Checkbox
            checked={value}
            onChange={e => {
              onChange(e.target.checked);
            }}
          />
        }
        label="Enable text input?"
        labelPlacement="end"
      />
    );
  }}
/>
<Controller
  name="text-input"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
    return (
      <TextField
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        disabled={/* WHAT TO DO HERE???? */}
      />
    );
  }}
/>;
</form>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use `watch`:

```
const {register, watch} = useForm();

return ( 
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" ref={register} name="input-a" />
  <input ref={register} name="input-b" disabled={!watch("input-a")} />
</div>
);
```

Comment: What if we have several more inputs which depends on the values of the first inputs? For example, if we have 5 inputs, and the 2 input depends on the first, the 3d one depends on the 1st and the 2nd one to render, the resulting code wouldn't be unscallable? since we are going to have a lot of watch conditions to render the next inputs and so on

Comment: @LuisEdwards Well, to get the form values in `react-hook-form` you have 3 options: `state`, `getValues`, and `watch`. if you always want the latest values, use `watch`; if not, use `getValues` because it doesn't trigger rerender. either way, in your usecase using them for several inputs, would be unscalable :/